# Configuring Imagick on Azure WebApp with Composer enabled

Tags: php, azure, composer-php, imagick

I've managed to get Imagick working on Azure WebApp, following @Saurabh Kumar manual http://techblog.saurabhkumar.com/2015/12/setting-up-imagemagick-for-php-on-azure.html (replaced with relevant packages for php7), however once I enable Composer extension on the same App, Azure is loosing PATH for imagick.

[There is a comment on MS blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2015/12/07/php-imagemagick-on-azure-web-apps/) suggesting to edit the Composer applicationHost.xdt instead of creating a new applicationHost.xdt file for Imagick, if there is Composer installed. 
I've tried it but it crushed the whole app (HTTP Error 503).

Is there a way to make both Imagick and Composer work on Azure WebApp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced your issue on my side. After some investigation, I found a way to make both Imagick and Composer work on Azure WebApp. I know it is not beautiful, however, it does work.

1) Go into `D:\home\SiteExtensions\ComposerExtension` fodler using FTP or SCM (websitename.SCM.azurewebsites.net), and delete `applicationHost.xdt` file.

2) Merge the content of the deleted file above to `D:\home\site\applicationHost.xdt`. After that the `xdt` file should look something like this:

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform"> 
   <system.applicationHost>
     <sites>
       <site name="%XDT_SCMSITENAME%" xdt:Locator="Match(name)">
         <application path="/Composer"  applicationPool="%XDT_APPPOOLNAME%" xdt:Transform="Insert">
          <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="%XDT_EXTENSIONPATH%" />
        </application>
      </site>
    </sites>
  </system.applicationHost>
  <system.webServer> 
    <runtime xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing"> 
      <environmentVariables xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing"> 
        <add name="MAGICK_HOME" value="d:\home\site\ext\" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" /> 
        <add name="MAGICK_CODER_MODULE_PATH" value="d:\home\site\imagickwin\" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" /> 
        <add name="APPSETTING_COMMAND" value="%HOME%\SiteExtensions\ComposerExtension\Hooks\deploy.cmd" />
        <add name="COMPOSER_ARGS" value="--prefer-dist --no-dev --optimize-autoloader --no-progress" />
        <add name="PATH" value="%PATH%;%PATH%d:\home\site\ext\;%HOME%\SiteExtensions\ComposerExtension\Commands;%APPDATA%\Composer\vendor\bin" />
      </environmentVariables> 
    </runtime> 
    <rewrite xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
      <rules xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
        <rule name="RequestBlockingRule1" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{URL}" pattern="vendor/(.*)$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="403" statusReason="Forbidden: Access is denied." statusDescription="You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied." />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer> 
</configuration>
```

3) Now, restart your app, they should work together.

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you, it worked this time! Not sure why it didn't work before, I guess I might have added some wrong argument that caused PHP general error. I wish there was more elegant solution from Microsoft though and lets hope it won't cause issues with Imagick later.